# An injective neighborhood of a compact subset

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove the following statement :

Let $X$ be a (Hausdorff) space, $Y$ a metric space, $f : X \to Y$ a continuous function, $K$ a compact subset of $X$. If $f$ is injective on $K$, and if each $x \in K$ has an open neighborhood on which $f$ is injective, then there is an open neighborhood of $K$ on which $f$ is injective.

I think the followings may be useful :

1. Defining a function $G:X\times X\to \Bbb R$ by $G(x,y)=d(f(x),f(y))$ where $d$ is the metric on $Y$.
2. the generalized tube lemma

But, I got stuck. How do I have to proceed?

Comment: Is there any problem with the set $\cup_{x\in K}U_x $, where $U_x $ is the open neighborhood of $x $ on which $f $ is injective?

Comment: The $U_x$'s form an open cover of $K$, so we can choose a finite subcover of it, an the union of the finite subcover is a candidate for the desired neighborhood of $K$ but I couldn't show that $f$ is injective on it. I cannot use the assumption that $Y$ is a metric space

Comment: Okay, now I see the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When $X$ is a metric space:

Assume the result is false. Then there exists sequences $x_n,y_n \in K$, $a_n,b_n \in X$ such that $f(a_n)=f(b_n)$, $d(x_n,a_n) < 1/n$, $d(y_n,b_n) < 1/n$, $a_n \neq b_n$.

We can assume (by taking subsequences) that $x_n \rightarrow a \in K$, $y_n \rightarrow b \in K$, thus $a$ (resp. $b$) is the limit of $a_n$ (resp. $b_n$).

Thus $f(a)=f(b)$, hence $a=b$. There is an open neighborhood $U$ of $a$ such that $f_{|U}$ is injective. So if $n$ is large enough, $a_n,b_n \in U$ so $a_n=b_n$, a contradiction.